# How to make a group list alphabetically on each first character of a name with Listview.builder in FLutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm new in Flutter. How to make a group list alphabetically on each first character of a name like A for {Annisa,Amir} and B for {Bagas, Berry} etc... with Listview.builder and listTile in FLutter. I want to display like this:

[image]

and this is My code:

```
body: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
child: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    SearchBox(),
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: member.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(),
              title: Text(member[index]["name"]),
              subtitle: Text(member[index]["noHp"]),
              trailing: StatusBadge(status: member[index]["status"]),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

in file jsonDummy.dart

```
List<dynamic> member = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Annisa Zahra",
    "noHp": "+62856983764",
    "status": "Done",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Amir Husna",
    "noHp": "+62856983764",
    "status": "Progress",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Azrul wahid",
    "noHp": "+62856983764",
    "status": "Progress",
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Bagas Kurniawan",
    "noHp": "+62856983764",
    "status": "Progress",
  },
  etc.....
];
```

Comment: Try this package  https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. We can use the ListView.separated builder which can add Widgets between the ListTiles.
2. Problem here: It does not add the separator above the first item, so we have to add it manually by providing a row.
3. In the separated builder we check if the first letter of both members distinguish. If this is the case we add a separator.

This is the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.separated(
              itemCount: member.length,
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                if (index == member.length - 1) return const SizedBox.shrink();
                String firstLetterA = (member[index]["name"] as String)[0];
                String firstLetterB = (member[index + 1]["name"] as String)[0];
                if (firstLetterA != firstLetterB) {
                  return Text(firstLetterB);
                } 
                return const SizedBox.shrink();
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                if (index == 0) {
                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const Text("A"),
                      getCardByIndex(index),
                    ],
                  );
                }
                return getCardByIndex(index);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Card getCardByIndex(int index) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: const CircleAvatar(),
        title: Text(member[index]["name"]),
        subtitle: Text(member[index]["noHp"]),
        onTap: () {},
      )
    );
  }
```